# Java generics in type parameter hiding

Tags: java, generics, interface, wildcard

Suppose I have an interface like so

```
public interface Foo<Ret, Arg> {
    public Ret doSomething(Arg arg);
}
```

And a concrete implementing class that only has package visibility.

```
class FooImpl<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> implements Foo<Ret, Arg>, Bar<Ret, Arg1, Arg2> {
    // This class also implements something else making use of Arg2, so you cannot safely remove it
    // But nothing relating to Arg2 is needed to create a FooImpl
}
```

(An example of how this might happen is the implementation of `Foo` and `Bar` in `FooImpl` forwards methods declared by the two interfaces to one varargs method)

Now, suppose there is a static method somewhere in the same package that returns a `FooImpl` as a `Foo`.  One would think that you could use `return new FooImpl<Ret, Arg1, ?>(...)`, when in fact you can't (you have to use a concrete dummy type as `Arg2`, i.e.. `return new FooImpl<Ret, Arg1, Object>(...)`, say).

Any idea why this is, especially as the fact that the `Foo` interface and the package visibility effectively hides the `FooImpl` from whatever is using the static method?  Is it because of the fact that one could still use reflection to some extent in order to get to the `Bar` parts of `FooImpl`, where a concrete type is needed?

Comment: What is the error message that you get? Do you get it for the constructor or when trying to cast it for the return? And what is the return signature of that static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java compiler tries hard not to be smart. There are many situations when it is obvious that it doesn't need some information to produce correct code but it still complains. When Java was invented, the world had seen C with it's sloppy attitude to try to compile everything, no matter how dangerous or stupid. The goal for `javac` was to make sure people can't [shoot themselves into the foot easily](http://m5p.com/~pravn/foot.html).

Therefore, it assumes that there is a reason that you mention `Arg2` - if it wasn't necessary for something, you surely wouldn't have put it into the code.

Solutions:

1. Assign a type when you implement `Bar`: `class FooImpl<Ret, Arg1> implements Foo<Ret, Arg>, Bar<Ret, Arg1, Object>`
2. Create a `BetterFooImpl<Ret, Arg1> extends FooImpl<Ret, Arg1, Object>`. That hides the third type argument from consumers of the API.
3. Try to get rid of the third parameter of `Bar`
4. Use generics carefully. It might be surprising, but there are situations where generics simply don't work well. This is usually because of subtle implementation details which cause an explosion of `@SuppressWarning` annotations. When this happens, I ask on SO and when I can't find a solution that I can understand, I remove the generics. It's more important to write maintainable code than finding clever ways through the generics maze.

Answer (score 4):

I think this has nothing to do with your particular design.

You just cannot instantiate types with wild cards.

This won't work, either:

```
return new ArrayList<?>();
```

And if it did, would it do anything else than

```
return new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You need a concrete class, but that does not mean that you need to show it in your factory method signature:

```
static <A,B> Foo<A,B> makeFoo(){
    return new FooImpl<A,B, SomeTypeThatNoOneNeedsToSee>();
}
```